# Which to use "do" or "does" to emphasize with third person singular?

Tags: do-support

For example, I can say "*I do like apples*". May I similarly say

> *A kitten do like to play with a clew*

or should I use *does* instead. 
Also, in sentences like

> *Only then do/does it really matter, which choice you make.*

Comment: I meant a ball of worsted (like in "Alice Through The Looking-Glass"). I asked this question, because I remember myself confused several times by hearing/reading something like the last sentence I put: "Only then *do* it really matter...", so "*do*" was used with third singular. Similarly, I heard an infinitive used in smth. like: "He heard the referee *go* [not goes, not went] "foul!" ". (But perhaps, the ending "es" was swallowed, I am not sure). Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I (1st person singular) do like words.

A kitten (3rd person singular) does like words.

If you want to stress the verb in the second sentence you'll probably want to use an adverb.  "A kitten truly does like words."  The word *do* in your first sentence is part of the verb, not a modifier.  I can see how you might be confused if you are learning English the way it is generally taught nowadays, i.e. without a formal study of English grammar.

Answer (score 4):

In English, a verb phrase includes an optional auxiliary verb (or "helping verb") such as "have", "will", "shall", "do" or "be". The auxiliary verb appears in front of the main verb.

When the auxiliary verb is present, the auxiliary verb takes on the inflections of tense (past, present) as well as person (I, you, they, ...).

The main verb remains in an infinitive or participle form.

For instance, suppose the auxiliary is "have" and the main verb is "be". In this case, "be" turns into the participle "been", and then "have" undergoes various inflections:

> I *have* been there.
>
> I *had* been there.
>
> She *has* been there.

The "been" does not change. Now if you don't have an auxiliary verb, then the main verb takes the inflections:

> I *am* there.
>
> I *was* there.
>
> She *is* there.

It is exactly the same thing when the auxiliary is "do", and the main verb is "like". The auxiliary "do" takes the inflections. Here, "like" is in a nonpast/infinitive form rather than a past participle:

> I *do* like ..
>
> She *does* like ..
>
> She *did* like ...

If we take out "do", then "like" has to take on the inflections for person and tense:

> I *like*
>
> She *likes*
>
> She *liked*

It is the same for all other auxiliaries. For instance "shall" with "go":

> I shall go
>
> I should go

and "will" with "go":

> I will go
>
> I would go

or "be" with "go":

> I am gone
>
> She is gone
>
> She was gone

The trick is knowing which form of the main verb to use: participle or plain present. "I am go" and "I will gone" are ungrammatical!

Answer (score 1):

From my early lessons in English grammar comes the following:

*I, you, he/she/it* are all singular (first, second, and third persons respectively) and therefore take a singular verb, including for example the two-word verb "do like."

> I **do** like carrots.
>   You **do** like carrots.
>   He/She/It **does** like carrots.

We/you/they are all plural (first, second, and third persons respectively) and therefore take a plural verb, including for example the two-word verb "do like."

> We **do** like carrots.
>   You **do** like carrots.
>   They **do** like carrots.

The question arises naturally, then, "Why is it **correct** for me to say 'I do like' (since I am just one, singular person) and **incorrect** to say 'He do like' (since he's just one, singular person)? Shouldn't both sentences contain "do like," as in 'I do like' and 'He do like'?"

The answer is no. For some strange reason, in English both "do" and "does" can function as singular, but you can use only "do" with first-person singular. That's the rule, even though it doesn't make sense and seems (and is) inconsistent!