# Unsure about this sentence

Tags: grammar

"I haven't completed any official course, but I did read a number of books on the subject."

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: which portion is doubtful? what's your study about it? Proofreading is off topic here.

Comment: i'm unsure about using "did"

Comment: *did* is okay that way in this sentence. *I have not gone to the church but I **did** inform Julie to go and meet Sushie.*

Comment: yeah but when you use "did", you have to state exact timing right?

Comment: That's okay when you precisely (do stress) to **did** it means that you are justifying that act with previous clause. Here, you are stressing that though you did not do any authentic course, your knowledge is sufficient as you are thorough on that subject. You have read a lot of books on it.

Comment: Many thanks, I have formed this sentence rather unconsciously.

Comment: You are welcome. That's okay. We are here to help only ;)

Comment: See also: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/14768/3281, and http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/12003/3281